# How to redirect user based on usertype

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm setting up a **login(reactjs, nodejs)** system that will redirect users based on usertype.

After checking if user is valid, am supposed to redirect user based on usertype.
  The usertypes are buyer and seller.

```js
// sigin route
router.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    db.select('email', 'hash').from('login')
        .where('email', '=', req.body.email)
        .then(data => {
            const isValid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data[0].hash);
            if (isValid) {
                db.select('*').from('users')
                    .where('email', '=', req.body.email)
                    .then(user => {
                        res.json(user[0])
                    })
                    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get user'))
            }

        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Wrong Credentials'))
})
```

Comment: You need to handle this on your client side `reactjs`. So please upload your `reactjs` code.

Answer (score 0):

you can add one more column in your table for type of user like user type and if user email and password is correct it will return you user then you can check as

```
if(user.type === 'seller'){
    res.redirect('/sellerdashboard')
} else {
    res.redirect('/buyerdashboard')
}
```